# how to set response code 500 in azure api policy in definition

Tags: azure-api-management, outbound

how to set response code 500 in azure api policy in definition.

I want to handle soap error in outbound policy of API management.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
<faultcode>5</faultcode>
<faultstring>Session expired. Try to relogin.</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this to set response code with 500:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply.
But even though i have added this i am getting 200 response code .I did like this result is shown as HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
date: Thu, 20 May 2021 07:53:50 GMT
expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT   <return-response xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
      <set-status code="502" reason="Internal soap error" />
      <set-header name="Context-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>text/plain</value>
      </set-header>
</return-response>